# How to use TorQ framework to manage multiple kdb plants

Tags: kdb, torq

I started using TorQ for a personal project.

I have an app which has 3 plants.

```
1 for options 
1 for equities 
1 for fx
```

(I am using some mock data I found around)

For my system I will have 1 tp, 1 rdb, 2 hdbs and 1 wdb for each plant.
There will be 3-5 gw able to access all plants.

```
tp options  -> rdb options                  -> 
            -> wdb options -> hdb options   -> gw options

tp equities -> rdb equities                 -> 
            -> wdb equities -> hdb equities -> gw equities 

.
.
.
```

Gatways should be able to access all RDBS and HDBS and generally be able to switch between the plants (ie. someone can do a select from tab1 and the gw will be smart enough to know where that tab1 is)

My question is :

Should I start 3 TorQ plants or modify TorQ to use a procname variable to differentiate between the 3 plants? (ie rdb will only subscribe to all tickerplanttypes where tickerplantnames OptiPx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your system under a single TorQ stack may be more convenient as then all connection information for your rdbs and hdbs will be readily available from the discovery process and you won't have to worry about any external connection management.

You can find some more information on how to set up your connections if you decide to use separate stacks here
[TorQ Connection Management](https://dataintellecttech.github.io/TorQ/conn/)